# command php artisan make:auth not defined using Lumen Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5, lumen

fairly new to using Lumen/Laravel and trying to use Authentication on my Laravel Lumen (5.5) project, the reason why i am using version 5.5 is so that it can access my MySQL. Is it possible to manually define make:auth if so how otherwise how will i manage to create my authentication

Comment: Which one are you using, Laravel or Lumen? I'm pretty sure `make` commands are not part of Lumen, but they should work in Laravel. You can always code it yourself.

Comment: Lumen and make:migration and seeder are defined. I was just wondering if it is a fixable problem or i have to do it manually you see.

Comment: Have you seen the piece of documentation? Namely the red parts usually help out alot: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication